# 'object is not a function' when joining two json arrays with angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm getting an error when I run the 'getPriceSummary' function below **more than once**. I call the function from the UI and then add one part of JSON to another and send it off to an API...

```
   (function() {
     var quoteBuild = angular.module('quoteApp');
     quoteBuild.controller('builderController', function($scope) {

       $scope.priceSummaryRequest = {
         "Groups": [{
             "Products": []
           },
           // other stuff
         ]
       };

       // this is dynamically created in the UI - this is just an examply of whats created
       $scope.selectedProducts.Products = [{
         "ProductCode": "Code1",
       }, {
         "ProductCode": "Code1",
       }, ]

       $scope.getPriceSummary = function() {

         $scope.priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products.push.apply($scope.priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products, $scope.selectedProducts.Products);
         // get prices back from the api
         productsServices.getSolutionPrice($scope.priceSummaryRequest)
           .then(function(res) {})
           .finally(function() {});
       }
     });
   }());
```

As mentioned, the first time $scope.getPriceSummary runs it works, but if I run it again I get this error

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at hb.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis....)    
at Cc.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (https://ajax.googleapis....)    
at l.$get.l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis....)    
at l.$get.l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis....)    
at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis...)    
at HTMLTableRowElement.n.event.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis...)    
at HTMLTableRowElement.n.event.add.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis...)
(anonymous function)angular.js:8548 $getangular.js:14489     $get.l.$applyangular.js:21427 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle
```

which I think is related to where I am doing the push.apply. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I'm not sure if this relevant, but I call the getPriceSummary function from a table row like this

```
<tr ng-click="getPriceSummary(I pass prices in here - just removed it)"  ng-repeat="prices in productVariant.Prices">
```

Comment: Please write what you want to do where you call the push function.

Comment: I want to push the products array of 'selectedproducts' into 'pricesummaryrequest'

Comment: How do you want the last results to be in this example?

Comment: Like this (check the script file) http://plnkr.co/edit/R6w87Edwq5H37Ruh8Anu?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
  var priceSummaryRequest = {
    "Groups": [{
        "Products": []
      },
      // other stuff
    ]
  };

  var selectedProducts = {};
  selectedProducts.Products = [{
    "ProductCode": "Code1",
  }, {
    "ProductCode": "Code1",
  }, ];

  selectedProducts.Products.forEach(function(product) {
    priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products.push(product);
  });

  console.dir(priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IuneSeIIGQjby2V8rlZK?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN [push.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) needs to be done from the prototype. Try:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(
  $scope.priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products,
  $scope.selectedProducts.Products);
```

Alternatively you can simply:

```
$scope.selectedProducts.Products.forEach(function(item){
      $scope.priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it is still the same error... Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.priceSummaryRequest.Groups[0].Products, $scope.selectedProducts.Products);

Comment: push.apply actually merges the two arrays, so my first guess is that the two arrays must contain objects that are comparable (same JSON structure?). If you don't want to merge but simply add (as per your comment), try firstArray.push(secondArray)

Comment: Yes i had tried that before - but I ended up with "Products": [[ //products in here ]] - note the double [[ ]]. so thats why I used push.apply